# Java: How to get Unicode name of a character (or its type category)?

Tags: java, unicode, character

The [`Character`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpace%28char%29) class in Java defines methods which check a given `char` argument for equality with certain Unicode chars or for belonging to some type category. These chars and type categories are named.

As stated in given javadoc, examples for named chars are
`HORIZONTAL TABULATION`, `FORM FEED`, ...;
example for named type categories are
`SPACE_SEPARATOR`, `PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR`, ...

However, being `byte` or `int` values instead of enums, the name of these types are "hidden" at runtime.

So, **is there a possibility to get characters' and/or type categories' names at runtime?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

JDK7 will have a

```
String getName(int codepoint)
```

function (READ: a “static method” in class java.lang.Character) that will turn a codepoint into its official Unicode name.

Javadoc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getName%28int%29

Comment: Seems that it's be JDK7; http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getName%28int%29

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Use the [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/) library. It has a the entire UCD and an API to get things out of it.

Answer (score 3):

The `Character` class supports category info. Look at [`Character.getType(char)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType(char)) for the category. But i do not think, you can get the character names.

Answer (score 2):

I posted a .NET implementation here: [Finding out Unicode character name in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087682/finding-out-unicode-character-name-in-net/5708388#5708388)

That should be very easy to port to Java.  All you need is to download the Unicode Database: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt, and the Java equivalent of a string splitting method and a Dictionary class, both of which I'm sure exist in Java.

This is a simple alternative to downloading some bloated library with tons of Unicode methods that Java and .NET probably both already support.

Answer (score 0):

The names are [standard](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt) and may be used subject to certain [limitations](http://www.unicode.org/copyright.html).

Comment: Oh no, the copyright... I hope there will be no time when people will not be able to speak without accepting some "Unitalk" copyright license...

Comment: There are no limits on the use of these names in this sort of context. The UTC is happy to have anyone use them in this sort of case.

Comment: IIUC, the provisions are specified in Exhibit 1(a)(b)(c), cited above.

Answer (score 0):

For the character name, one can use `Character.getName(int)`. However, for general category it is not so convenient:

```
// attach String names to Character constants
Map<Byte, String> unicodeCategories = new HashMap<>();
unicodeCategories.put(Character.COMBINING_SPACING_MARK, "Mc");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.CONNECTOR_PUNCTUATION, "Pc");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.CONTROL, "Cc");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.CURRENCY_SYMBOL, "Sc");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.DASH_PUNCTUATION, "Pd");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER, "Nd");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.ENCLOSING_MARK, "Me");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.END_PUNCTUATION, "Pe");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.FINAL_QUOTE_PUNCTUATION, "Pf");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.FORMAT, "Cf");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.INITIAL_QUOTE_PUNCTUATION, "Pi");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.LETTER_NUMBER, "Nl");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.LINE_SEPARATOR, "Zl");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER, "Ll");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.MATH_SYMBOL, "Sm");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.MODIFIER_LETTER, "Lm");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.MODIFIER_SYMBOL, "Sk");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.NON_SPACING_MARK, "Mn");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.OTHER_LETTER, "Lo");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.OTHER_NUMBER, "No");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.OTHER_PUNCTUATION, "Po");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.OTHER_SYMBOL, "So");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR, "Zp");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.PRIVATE_USE, "Co");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.SPACE_SEPARATOR, "Zs");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.START_PUNCTUATION, "Ps");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.SURROGATE, "Cs");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.TITLECASE_LETTER, "Lt");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.UNASSIGNED, "Cn");
unicodeCategories.put(Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER, "Lu");
// use the map to extract category name from the constant
char ch = 'a'; // OR int ch = Character.codePointAt("a", 0);
String category = unicodeCategories.get( (byte) (Character.getType(ch) ) );
```