# How to get character by its (unicode) name in Java? I need the reverse of Character.getName(int codePoint)

Tags: java, unicode

How do I look up a character or int codepoint in Java using its Unicode name?

For example, if

```
Character.getName('\u00e4')
```

returns `"LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS"`, how do I perform the reverse operation (i.e. go from `"LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS"` to `'\u00e4'`) using "plain" Java?

**Edit: To stop the torrent of comments what I want or I don't want**, here is what I would do in Python:

```
"\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS}" # this gives me what I want as a literal

unicodedata.lookup("LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS") # a dynamic version
```

Now, the question is: do the same in Java.

And, BTW, I don't want to "print unicode escapes" -- actually getting hex for char is easy, but I want a char bearing given name.

**To put it in other words** I want to do the reverse of what `Character.getName(int)` does.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [How to get Unicode name of a character (or its type category)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443325/java-how-to-get-unicode-name-of-a-character-or-its-type-category)

Comment: @Jonathan OP wants to go the other way around

Comment: user3580294 could u explain how ?

Comment: `char c = '\u00e4'; System.out.println(c);` Doesn't print out what you want? (not on a comp, can't test). @user3580294 mentioned that the "possible duplicate" is the opposite of what you want to do, so if so, please clarify better.

Comment: @KickButtowski OP seems to want to go from the full name of the Unicode character to the escape sequence for that character (i.e. `"LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS"` --> `'\u00e4'`). Jonathan's link tells how to do `'\u00e4'` --> `"LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS"`.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I don't think OP wants to just print the character. OP wants to go from the full name of the character to its escape sequence, so something like `"UPPERCASE A" --> 'A'` (don't know if that's valid Unicode, but something like that)

Comment: @user3580294, please avoid such edit tasks like the one you completed on this question. It is just too minor, and unfortunately some ops approve it anyway.

Comment: how u can drive a Unicode from a string?

Comment: @rekaszeru Will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: @KickButtowski That's exactly what OP is asking

Comment: @rekaszeru - Why would you say such a thing?  The fact that two people have now misunderstood the  question indicates that it needed clarifying.  user3580294 did a good thing.

Comment: I agree this question needs more clarification

Comment: it will be so dazzling how this question will be answered

Comment: I also agree on the original question needed more clarification, I was referring the last edit by @user3580294 that got approved. His/her first edit was totally correct.

Comment: I'd say the opposite.  His/her first edit was very minor, and a little pointless.  His/her second edit was a really good one.  Are you sure you're not looking at the list the wrong way around?

Comment: And I was just about to do another one before OP edited and made cleared away all doubts...

Comment: @user3580294, thanks. Now that we all agree what I was asking about... let's find some cool answer, because having to write hex in the editor really sucks. And using UTF-8 as source file encoding does not help either, since many different things look the same in Unicode.

Comment: Check my edited answer (its the one that was downvoted to near death). Also, check the source file for Character to see how `getName` works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For release JDK 9 and later, using the static method [`Character.codePointOf(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#codePointOf(java.lang.String)) is the simplest approach:

> public static int codePointOf​(String name)
>
> Returns the code point value of the Unicode character specified by the given Unicode character name.

This works for all Uniocde characters, and not just those in the Basic Multilingual Plane. For example, running this code on Java 12 ...

```
String s1 = "LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS";
int cp1 = Character.codePointOf(s1);
System.out.println("Unicode name \"" + Character.getName(cp1) + "\" => code point " + cp1 + " => character " + Character.toString(cp1));

String s2 = "EYES";
int cp2 = Character.codePointOf(s2);
System.out.println("Unicode name \"" + Character.getName(cp2) + "\" => code point " + cp2 + " => character " + Character.toString(cp2));

String s3 = "DNA Double Helix"; // Only works with JDK12 and later. Otherwise java.lang.IllegalArgumentException is thrown.
int cp3 = Character.codePointOf(s3);
System.out.println("Unicode name \"" + Character.getName(cp3) + "\" => code point " + cp3 + " => character " + Character.toString(cp3));
```

...produces this output...

```
Unicode name "LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS" => code point 228 => character ä
Unicode name "EYES" => code point 128064 => character 
Unicode name "DNA DOUBLE HELIX" => code point 129516 => character
```

To summarize the conversions:

- For code point => Unicode name, use `Character.getName(codepoint)`
- For code point => character representation, use `Character.toString(codepoint)`
- For Unicode name => code point, use `Character.codePointOf(name)`
- For Unicode name => character representation, no JDK method currently exists. Instead, do it indirectly, using the code point of the Unicode name, as shown above. For example: `Character.toString(Character.codePointOf("LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS"));`.

Notes:

- Be sure that the JDK release being used supports the specified Unicode names. For example, the character with the Unicode name *"DNA Double Helix"* was added to Unicode 11 which is only supported by JDK releases >= 12. If you run using an earlier JDK release you will get an `IllegalArgumentException` when calling `Character.codePointOf("DNA Double Helix")`.
- If a white square is being shown in place of the Unicode character then try changing the font (e.g. *Segoe UI Emoji* for rendering Emoji characters).

Answer (score 5):

The [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/) library can help you here. It has a class `UCharacter` with [`getCharFromName`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/lang/UCharacter.html#getCharFromName%28java.lang.String%29) and other related methods that can map from various types of character name strings back to the `int` code points they represent.

However, if you are working with hard coded character names (i.e. quoted string literals in the source code) then it would be far more efficient to do the translation once - use the `\u` escape in the source code and add a comment with the full name if necessary - rather than incur the cost of parsing the name tables at runtime every time. If the character names are coming from reading a file or similar then obviously you will have to convert at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. I know ICU4J is the answer to all Unicode headaches, but I want "plain" Java (as in question).

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen as the other answers have demonstrated, if you don't want to use a third party library then you'll basically have to implement the same set of algorithms yourself. What makes your own re-implementation any more "plain Java" than using an existing (widely used and tested) open source library that has already done the work for you?

Comment: Difference is -- dependency. It's so basic an operation I'm continuously surprised there is no sane "plain Java" answer -- especially since Python has this since ever? Today I do exactly that: `kcharselect` to get `\u` escape and write the name in comment. But this all: waste of time, error prone and dangerous duplication.

Comment: Piotr, I don't understand your objection to depending on a library.  Most commercially written Java code depends on several libraries.  Professional programmers recognise that it's not cost-effective to go round re-inventing wheels.  No matter what your problem is, if someone else has solved it, there's seldom any reason not to use their solution.

Comment: Maybe Piotr is not obsessed with cost-effectiveness but with leanness, maybe he is not a professional but a hobbyist programmer, maybe he is not building commercial code but free software code.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this class relying only on "plain" Java will be useful to someone. It utilizes lazily populated lookup table that may be cleared at any time via `reset(false)` call to free memory (with the possibility to automatically fill the table and use it again if needed). If the characters being looked for are at the lower Unicode blocks (as is usually the case), then fill time of this table is almost unnoticeable. I added optional possibility to pre-fill the whole table via call to `reset(true)`.

Also note that there is known [Unicode name collision](http://www.unicode.org/Public/11.0.0/ucd/NameAliases.txt) between `U+0007` and `U+1F514`. Java's `Character.getName()` still returns "BELL" for the former. The class being presented tries to fix this at least for the reverse operation, returning `U+0007` for the approved unique name "ALERT" assigned to it.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class UnicodeTable {
    public static final char INVALID_CHAR = '\uFFFF';
    private static final Map<String, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<>();
    private static boolean incomplete;
    private static int lastLookup;

    static {
        reset(false);
    }

    public static int getCodePoint(String name) {
        Integer cp = charMap.get(name);
        if (cp == null && incomplete) {
            while (++lastLookup <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT) {
                String uName = Character.getName(lastLookup);
                if (uName != null) {
                    charMap.put(uName, lastLookup);
                    if (uName.equals(name))
                        return lastLookup;
                }
            }
            incomplete = false;
        }
        return cp == null ? INVALID_CHAR : cp;
    }

    public static char getChar(String name) {
        int cp = getCodePoint(name);
        return Character.isBmpCodePoint(cp) ? (char)cp : INVALID_CHAR;
    }

    private static final int ALERT = 0x000007;
    private static final int BELL = 0x01F514;

    public static void reset(boolean fillUp) {
        if (!fillUp) {
            charMap.clear();
            incomplete = true;
            lastLookup = Character.MIN_CODE_POINT - 1;
            charMap.put("ALERT", ALERT);
            String bName = Character.getName(BELL);
            if (bName.equals(Character.getName(ALERT))) {
                getCodePoint(bName);
                charMap.put(bName, BELL);
            }
        } else if (incomplete) {
            while (++lastLookup <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT) {
                String uName = Character.getName(lastLookup);
                if (uName != null)
                    charMap.put(uName, lastLookup);
            }
            incomplete = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at the source code for `Character.class`:

```
public static String getName(int codePoint) {
    if (!isValidCodePoint(codePoint)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    String name = CharacterName.get(codePoint);
    if (name != null)
        return name;
    ...
}
```

`CharacterName` is a package-private class which lazily initializes a `SoftReference<byte[]>` pool of character names (I think). One line in particular is of interest though, buried inside a series of different input stream constructors:

```
private static synchronized byte[] initNamePool() {
    ...
        return getClass().getResourceAsStream("uniName.dat");
    ...
}
```

<strike>Now, I've been doing some digging, and for some reason this `uniName.dat` doesn't seem to exist in OpenJDK's source. I did find a `uniName.dat` -- as part of my TeX Live distribution, strangely enough. Opening it up in a hex editor reveals jumbles of bytes -- so the contents are encoded somehow. How, I have no clue.</strike>  I'll take a second look at the source code, but it might take a while to decode, if I can figure it out at all.

In addition, the debugger in my copy of Eclipse appears to be broken (can't resolve variables for some reason or another), so I can't inspect the input stream to try to see where it's reading from.

So in short, doesn't seem you can do this in native Java unless you feel like copy-pasting the name pool code from `CharacterName`, or rolling your own code that deciphers this file (assuming you can find it)

---

Edit: Found `uniName.dat`! On my machine, located in `resources.jar` in the Java installation. Still a bunch of bytes. So you can either parse this file yourself (not a lot of fun, involves a lot of bit twiddling), or use a library (suggested above). So if you're restricted to native Java, you might want to take a look at the `CharacterName` class and see if you can get something into a `HashMap<String, Character>`.