# Java: Questions about using nested loops to create a deck of cards

Tags: java, loops

I am new to programming. I am trying to understand what the code means and how to create a deck of cards using a nested loop.

```
String [] rank = {"A" , "2" , "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" , "J", "Q" , "K"};

String [] suit = {"C", "D", "S" , "H"};

String [] deck = new String [52]
```

I tried to write:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++){    
         for (int j = 0; j < suit.length; j++){
             System.out.println(suit[i] + cards[j]);
           }
       }
```

but this will only print (CA, C2, C3, C4, DA...) my code will not print C5, C6...

but if I switch cards and suit, putting suit to outside loop, it will print all. I can't figure out why?

```
for(int i = 0; i < suit.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < rank.length; j++){
```

Also, the answer key is:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++){    
        for (int j = 0; j < suit.length; j++){
           deck[i + 13*j] = rank [i] + suit [j];
               }
           }
```

I really don't understand what does `deck[i + 13*j] = rank [i] + suit [j]` mean?

The answer key indicates if we want to change deck to put the cards in rank order in the array, we only need to change the code to `deck[4*i + j] = rank [i] + suit [j]`

I was wondering if anyone can help me understand what does `deck[4*i + j]` and `deck [i + 13*j]` mean in the code?

How to change my code to print "AC, AD, AS, AH, 2C, 2D, 2S, 2H...)?

Sorry, it is hard to describe my questions. Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: What is `cards[]`? Not shown here. You should be using `rank[]` surely. I would like to know exactly why my prior comment to this effect was deleted. Mystery to me.

Comment: Yes. So weird...I saw your post so I know I made a mistake. I edited my post and replied to you. But now my reply was also deleted. I can't see your original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your counter variable `i` is iterating through your `rank` and `j` iterates through `suit`, switching the variables will output them correctly:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++){    
     for (int j = 0; j < suit.length; j++){
         System.out.println(suit[j] + rank[i]);
       }
   }
```

Output:

```
CA
DA
SA
HA
C2
D2
S2
H2
C3
D3
S3
H3
C4
D4
S4
H4
C5
D5
S5
H5
C6
D6
S6
H6
C7
D7
S7
H7
C8
D8
S8
H8
C9
D9
S9
H9
C10
D10
S10
H10
CJ
DJ
SJ
HJ
CQ
DQ
SQ
HQ
CK
DK
SK
HK
```

However, if you want to store these values in the array, some more work is required.

`i` represents the current rank/value we are on while `j` represents the current suit we are on. If we want the list to go: `{CA,DA,SA,HA,C2,D2....}`, then we need to do some math.

`i` goes from 0 to 12 and `j` goes from 0 to 3. We want our first i-j pair, 0 and 0, to link to the first index of `deck`, 0, and our last i-j pair, 12 and 3, to link to our final index of `deck`, 51.

In terms of words, the index for every i-j pair is "the current rank we are on times 4 plus our current suite."

An "equation" to model this would be: Index = i * 4 + j

Thus our code would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++){    
     for (int j = 0; j < suit.length; j++){
         deck[4 * i + j] = suit[j] + rank[i];
        
       }
   }
```

Alternatively you could think of it as "Multiply our current suite by 13 and add our rank" which produces the code you provided. This would order by the ranks so it would go like:

`{CA,C2,C3,....DA,D2,D3....}`

Either one works!

I hope this helped, please let me know if you need any further details or clarification :)

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough!! I have been struggling with the math parts (e,g., i*4+j) for two days. Your explanation is extremely clear and helpful! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

As the [Answer by Ani M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71247889/642706) explained, you mixed up your `i` and `j`. As [this Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71247763/java-questions-about-using-nested-loops-to-create-a-deck-of-cards#comment125938670_71247763) explains, you mixed up your array names.

Let's improve your array names and contents. Usually a plural name makes more sense for a collection. And Unicode defines characters for card suits, so let's use them.

```java
String[] ranks = { "A" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9" , "10" , "J" , "Q" , "K" };
String[] suits = { "♠" , "♣" , "♥" , "♦" };  // Order in which they are defined in Unicode.
String[] deck = new String[ 52 ];
```

Using the [for-each](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) syntax rather than conventional `for` loop makes the code easier to read and write.

```java
int index = 0;
for ( String rank : ranks )
{
    for ( String suit : suits )
    {
        deck[ index ] = rank + suit;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Dump the results to console.

```java
System.out.println( "deck = " + Arrays.toString( deck ) );
```

When run.

```
Arrays.toString( ranks ) = [A, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K]
Arrays.toString( suits ) = [♠, ♣, ♥, ♦]
Arrays.toString( deck ) = [A♠, A♣, A♥, A♦, 2♠, 2♣, 2♥, 2♦, 3♠, 3♣, 3♥, 3♦, 4♠, 4♣, 4♥, 4♦, 5♠, 5♣, 5♥, 5♦, 6♠, 6♣, 6♥, 6♦, 7♠, 7♣, 7♥, 7♦, 8♠, 8♣, 8♥, 8♦, 9♠, 9♣, 9♥, 9♦, 10♠, 10♣, 10♥, 10♦, J♠, J♣, J♥, J♦, Q♠, Q♣, Q♥, Q♦, K♠, K♣, K♥, K♦]
```

So that code addresses your question of:

> How to change my code to print "AC, AD, AS, AH, 2C, 2D, 2S, 2H...)?

As for your answer-key solution, the clever math is explained in the other Answer by Ani M. I will simply add a note that such clever code can be more of a liability than an aid in real work. When trying to fix a bug in the middle of the night, such code can be a nightmare to debug and modify. Writing stupid-simple code is often preferable to flashy clever solutions.

---

For fun, let's get final cards represented by specific Unicode characters.

We can determine a character by its official name designated by the Unicode Consortium. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57541820/642706) on another Question about using [`Character.codePointOf(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#codePointOf(java.lang.String)) method.

```java
String[] ranks = { "ACE" , "TWO" , "THREE" , "FOUR" , "FIVE" , "SIX" , "SEVEN" , "EIGHT" , "NINE" , "TEN" , "JACK" , "QUEEN" , "KING" };
String[] suits = { "SPADES" , "CLUBS" , "HEARTS" , "DIAMONDS" };
String[] deck = new String[ 52 ];

int index = 0;  // Annoying zero-based counting.
for ( String rank : ranks )
{
    for ( String suit : suits )
    {
        String characterName = "PLAYING CARD " + rank + " OF " + suit;
        int codePoint = Character.codePointOf( characterName );
        String cardCharacter = Character.toString( codePoint );
        deck[ index ] = cardCharacter;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Results:

> Arrays.toString( deck ) = [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]

Comment: Wow...printing out the real cards is so cool!!! Thank you so much for sharing such "advanced" knowledge! Also, thank you for sharing your experience about how simple & straightforward code is preferable in the real-word. This is encouraging!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can just use a single loop.

- `i/13` will yield values `0-3` (integer math so fractions are dropped)
- `i%13` will yield values `0-12`

```
String [] rank = {"A" , "2" , "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" , "J", "Q" , "K"};
String [] suit = {"C", "D", "S" , "H"};
String [] deck = new String [52];
    
for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
    deck[i] = rank[i%13] + suit[i/13]; 
}
    
for (String card : deck) {
    System.out.println(card);
}
```

prints

```
AC
2C
3C
4C
5C
...
...
...
```

I assigned them as rank suit as that is how most cards are referred.