# How to display Unicode character names and their hexadecimal codes with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, unicode, emoji, surrogate-pairs

Since the default Windows PowerShell console fonts don't support Emojis, I'd like to display their surrogate pair hexadecimal codes and ideally also their Unicode character names for debugging purposes.

I know how to convert Emojis to a byte arrays, but I haven't figured out how to convert them to surrogate pair hexadecimal codes and Unicode character names.

```
$ThumbsUp = ""
$Bytes = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ThumbsUp)
# output
#240
#159
#145
#141
```

What I need is the following output:

```
$Hex = 0x1F44D 
$CharName = "Thumbs Up Sign"
```

I.e., the following command should convert the hexadecimal value back to an Emoj:

```
[char]::ConvertFromUtf32($Hex)
# output
#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the following script (a part of my broader project) could help. The script defines fairly sophisticated `Get-CharInfo` function.

Example: `'r Ř',0x1F44D|chr -OutUni -OutHex -OutStr  -IgnoreWhiteSpace`

```
r Ř
0x0072,0x002C,0x0158,0x0001F44D
\u0072\u002C\u0158\U0001F44D
Char CodePoint                              Category Description
---- ---------                              -------- -----------
   r {U+0072, 0x72}                  LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter R
   Ř {U+0158, 0xC5,0x98}             UppercaseLetter Latin Capital Letter R With Caron
   {U+1F44D, 0xF0,0x9F,0x91,0x8D}               So THUMBS UP SIGN (0xd83d,0xdc4d)
 #             ↑ UFF-8                               ↑ name          ↑ surrogates
```

The code (comment-based help at the end of the function body):

```
# Get-CharInfo function. Activate dot-sourced
# . .\_get-CharInfo_2.1.ps1
# Comment-based help at the end of the function body
# History notes at the very end of the script

if ( -not ('Microsofts.CharMap.UName' -as [type]) ) {
  Add-Type -Name UName -Namespace Microsofts.CharMap -MemberDefinition $(
    switch ("$([System.Environment]::SystemDirectory -replace 
                '\\', '\\')\\getuname.dll") {
    {Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Leaf} {@"
[DllImport("${_}", ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
private static extern int GetUName(ushort wCharCode, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder buf);

public static string Get(char ch) {
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(300);
    UName.GetUName(ch, sb);
    return sb.ToString();
}
"@
    }
    default {'public static string Get(char ch) { return "???"; }'}
    })
}
function Get-CharInfo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject],
                [System.Array])]
    param(
        # named or positional: a string or a number e.g. 'r Ř'
        # pipeline: an array of strings and numbers, e.g 'r Ř',0x1f44d
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObject,
        # + Write-Host Python-like Unicode literal e.g. \u0072\u0020\u0158\U0001F44D
        [Parameter()]
        [switch]$OutUni,
        # + Write-Host array of hexadecimals e.g. 0x0072,0x0020,0x0158,0x0001F44D
        [Parameter()]
        [switch]$OutHex,
        # + Write-Host concatenated string e.g. r Ř
        [Parameter()]
        [switch]$OutStr,
        # choke down whitespaces ( $s -match '\s' ) from output
        [Parameter()]
        [switch]$IgnoreWhiteSpace,
        # from https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$UnicodeData = 'D:\Utils\CodePages\UnicodeData.txt'
    )
    begin {
        Set-StrictMode -Version latest
        if ( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty( $UnicodeData) ) { $UnicodeData = '::' }
        Function ReadUnicodeRanges {
            if ($Script:UnicodeFirstLast.Count -eq 0) {
                $Script:UnicodeFirstLast = @'
                    First,Last,Category,Description
                    128,128,Cc-Control,Padding Character
                    129,129,Cc-Control,High Octet Preset
                    132,132,Cc-Control,Index
                    153,153,Cc-Control,Single Graphic Character Introducer
                    13312,19903,Lo-Other_Letter,CJK Ideograph Extension A
                    19968,40956,Lo-Other_Letter,CJK Ideograph
                    44032,55203,Lo-Other_Letter,Hangul Syllable
                    94208,100343,Lo-Other_Letter,Tangut Ideograph
                    101632,101640,Lo-Other_Letter,Tangut Ideograph Supplement
                    131072,173789,Lo-Other_Letter,CJK Ideograph Extension B
                    173824,177972,Lo-Other_Letter,CJK Ideograph Extension C
                    177984,178205,Lo-Other_Letter,CJK Ideograph Extension D
                    178208,183969,Lo-Other_Letter,CJK Ideograph Extension E
                    183984,191456,Lo-Other_Letter,CJK Ideograph Extension F
                    196608,201546,Lo-Other_Letter,CJK Ideograph Extension G
                    983040,1048573,Co-Private_Use,Plane 15 Private Use
                    1048576,1114109,Co-Private_Use,Plane 16 Private Use
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ',' |
                ForEach-Object {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        First      = [int]$_.First
                        Last       = [int]$_.Last
                        Category   = $_.Category
                        Description= $_.Description
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach ( $FirstLast in $Script:UnicodeFirstLast) {
                if ( $FirstLast.First -le $ch -and $ch -le $FirstLast.Last ) {
                    $out.Category = $FirstLast.Category
                    $out.Description = $FirstLast.Description + $nil
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        $AuxHex = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
        $AuxStr = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
        $AuxUni = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
        $Script:UnicodeFirstLast = @()
        $Script:UnicodeDataLines = @()
        function ReadUnicodeData {
            if ( $Script:UnicodeDataLines.Count -eq 0 -and (Test-Path $UnicodeData) ) {
                 $Script:UnicodeDataLines = @([System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines(
                        $UnicodeData, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8))
            }
            $DescrLine = $Script:UnicodeDataLines -match ('^{0:X4}\;' -f $ch)
            if ( $DescrLine.Count -gt 0) {
                $u0, $Descr, $Categ, $u3 = $DescrLine[0] -split ';'
                $out.Category = $Categ
                $out.Description = $Descr + $nil
            }
        }
        function out {
            param(
                [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true )] $ch,
                [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)]$nil=''
                 )
            if (0 -le $ch -and 0xFFFF -ge $ch) {
                [void]$AuxHex.Add('0x{0:X4}' -f $ch)
                $s = [char]$ch
                [void]$AuxStr.Add($s)
                [void]$AuxUni.Add('\u{0:X4}' -f $ch)
                $out = [pscustomobject]@{
                    Char      = $s
                    CodePoint = ('U+{0:X4}' -f $ch),
                        (([System.Text.UTF32Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($s) |
                            ForEach-Object { '0x{0:X2}' -f $_ }) -join ',')
                    Category  = [System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($ch)
                    Description = [Microsofts.CharMap.UName]::Get($ch)
                }
                if ( $out.Description -eq 'Undefined' ) { ReadUnicodeRanges }
                if ( $out.Description -eq 'Undefined' ) { ReadUnicodeData }
            } elseif (0x10000 -le $ch -and 0x10FFFF -ge $ch) {
                [void]$AuxHex.Add('0x{0:X8}' -f $ch)
                $s = [char]::ConvertFromUtf32($ch)
                [void]$AuxStr.Add($s)
                [void]$AuxUni.Add('\U{0:X8}' -f $ch)
                $out = [pscustomobject]@{
                    Char        = $s
                    CodePoint   = ('U+{0:X}' -f $ch),
                        (([System.Text.UTF32Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($s) |
                            ForEach-Object { '0x{0:X2}' -f $_ }) -join ',')
                    Category    = [System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo]::GetUnicodeCategory($s, 0)
                    Description = '???' + $nil
                }
                ReadUnicodeRanges 
                if ( $out.Description -eq ('???' + $nil) ) { ReadUnicodeData }
            } else {
                Write-Warning ('Character U+{0:X4} is out of range' -f $ch)
                $s = $null
            }
            if (( $null -eq $s ) -or
                ( $IgnoreWhiteSpace.IsPresent -and ( $s -match '\s' ))
               ) {
            } else {
                $out
            }
        }
    }
    process {
        #if ($PSBoundParameters['Verbose']) {
        #    Write-Warning "InputObject $InputObject, type = $($InputObject.GetType().Name)"
        #}
        if ( ($InputObject -as [int]) -gt 0xFFFF -and 
             ($InputObject -as [int]) -le 0x10ffff ) {
            $InputObject = [string][char]::ConvertFromUtf32($InputObject)
        }
        if ($null -cne ($InputObject -as [char])) {
            #Write-Verbose "A $([char]$InputObject) InputObject character"
            out $([int][char]$InputObject) ''
        } elseif (  $InputObject -isnot [string] -and 
                    $null -cne ($InputObject -as [int])) {
            #Write-Verbose "B $InputObject InputObject"
            out $([int]$InputObject) ''
        } else {
            $InputObject = [string]$InputObject
            #Write-Verbose "C $InputObject InputObject.Length $($InputObject.Length)"
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $InputObject.Length; ++$i) {
                if (  [char]::IsHighSurrogate($InputObject[$i]) -and 
                      (1+$i) -lt $InputObject.Length -and 
                      [char]::IsLowSurrogate($InputObject[$i+1])) {
                    $aux = ' (0x{0:x4},0x{1:x4})' -f [int]$InputObject[$i], 
                                                   [int]$InputObject[$i+1]
                    # Write-Verbose "surrogate pair $aux at position $i" 
                    out $([char]::ConvertToUtf32($InputObject[$i], $InputObject[1+$i])) $aux
                    $i++
                } else {
                    out $([int][char]$InputObject[$i]) ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
    end {
        if ( $OutStr.IsPresent -or $PSBoundParameters['Verbose']) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta -Object $($AuxStr -join '')
        }
        if ( $OutHex.IsPresent -or $PSBoundParameters['Verbose']) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan -Object $($AuxHex -join ',')
        }
        if ( $OutUni.IsPresent -or $PSBoundParameters['Verbose']) {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow -Object $($AuxUni -join '')
        }
    }
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Return basic information about supplied Unicode characters.

.DESCRIPTION
Return information about supplied Unicode characters:
    - as a PSCustomObject for programming purposes,
    - in a human-readable form, and
    - with optional additional output to the Information Stream.

Properties of the output PSCustomObject are as follows:

Char        The character itself (if renderable)
CodePoint   [string[]]Unicode CodePoint, its UTF-8 byte sequence
Category    General Category (long name or abbreviation)
Description Name (and surrogate pair in parentheses if apply).

.INPUTS
    An array of characters, strings and numbers (in any combination)
    can be piped to the function as parameter $InputObject, e.g as
    "ΧАB",[char]4301,191,0x1F3DE | Get-CharInfo
    or (the same in terms of decimal numbers) as
    935,1040,66,4301,191,127966 | Get-CharInfo

    On the other side, the $InputObject parameter supplied named
    or positionally must be of the only base type: either a number
    or a character or a string.
    The same input as a string:
    Get-CharInfo -InputObject 'ΧАBჍ¿'

    -Verbose implies all -OutUni, -OutHex and -OutStr

.OUTPUTS
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]
    [Object[]]    (an array like [PSCustomObject[]])

.NOTES
    The UnicodeData.txt file (if used) must be saved locally
    from https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt
    (currently Unicode 13.0.0)

    The UnicodeData.txt file is not required however, in such case,
    Get-CharInfo function could be return inaccurate properties
    Category and Description for characters above BMP, see Example-3.

.LINK
    Unicode® Standard Annex #44: Unicode Character Database (UCD)
.LINK
    https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/
.LINK
    https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values

.EXAMPLE
# full (first three lines are in the Information Stream)
'r Ř'|Get-CharInfo -OutUni -OutHex -OutStr -IgnoreWhiteSpace

r Ř
0x0072,0x0020,0x0158,0x0001F44D
\u0072\u0020\u0158\U0001F44D
Char CodePoint                             Category Description                
---- ---------                             -------- -----------                
   r {U+0072, 0x72}                 LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter R       
   Ř {U+0158, 0xC5,0x98}            UppercaseLetter Latin Capital Letter R W...
   {U+1F44D, 0xF0,0x9F,0x91,0x8D}              So THUMBS UP SIGN (0xd83d,0...


.EXAMPLE
# shortened version of above (output is the same)
'r Ř'|chr -Verbose -IgnoreWhiteSpace

.EXAMPLE
# inaccurate (inexact) output above BMP if missing UnicodeData.txt
'r Ř'|chr -Verbose -IgnoreWhiteSpace -UnicodeData .\foo.bar

r Ř
0x0072,0x0020,0x0158,0x0001F44D
\u0072\u0020\u0158\U0001F44D
Char CodePoint                             Category Description                
---- ---------                             -------- -----------                
   r {U+0072, 0x72}                 LowercaseLetter Latin Small Letter R       
   Ř {U+0158, 0xC5,0x98}            UppercaseLetter Latin Capital Letter R W...
   {U+1F44D, 0xF0,0x9F,0x91,0x8D}     OtherSymbol ??? (0xd83d,0xdc4d)        


.FUNCTIONALITY
Tested: Windows 8.1/64bit, Powershell 4
        Windows 10 /64bit, Powershell 5
        Windows 10 /64bit, Powershell Core 6.2.0
        Windows 10 /64bit, Powershell Core 7.1.0
#>
}
Set-Alias -Name chr -Value Get-CharInfo

<#
HISTORY NOTES

Origin by: http://poshcode.org/5234
           http://fossil.include-once.org/poshcode/artifact/5757dbbd0bc26c84333e7cf4ccc330ab89447bf679e86ddd6fbd3589ca24027e

License: CC0
  https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/legalcode

Activate dot-sourced like this (apply a real path instead of .\):
. .\Get-CharInfo.ps1

Improved by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz
             (to version 2)
#>
```

Comment: My Powershell is version 5.1. Why can't I run the Get-CharInfo command?... `Get-CharInfo : The term 'Get-CharInfo' is not recognized as a cmdlet name`

Comment: @Clamarc Read and follow the four comment lines… (save the code e.g. as `get_charinfo.ps1`, activate using [Dot Sourcing Operator .](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#dot-sourcing-operator-)).

Comment: I downloaded Get-CharInfo.ps1, but I'm not sure! Dot-source operator is a module I have to download in my powershell to be able to invoke Get-CharInfo.ps1 in my script or is it already part of powershell? In the comment of the Get-CharInfo script there is the information: `DOWNLOAD and DEFINITION OF THE FUNCTION irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/25694cbb8e10a7044b36a310e1243959/raw/Get-CharInfo.ps1 | iex` The above directly defines the function... what would that be?...sorry, it's my first time with this!

Comment: It's another script at gist.github.com/mklement0 with the same name. To dot-source it, use `. Get-CharInfo.ps1`.

Comment: OK, in which folder should I normally put Get-CharInfo.ps1 in order for it to be invoked by my script?

Comment: @Clamarc As usually, you can save any script to an arbitrary location (having in mind that _calling_ a script requires [the relative or fully qualified path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths) to a specified file).

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer - I only know how to get the UTF-32 code point:

```
$ThumbsUp = ""
$utf32bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF32.GetBytes( $ThumbsUp )
$codePoint = [System.BitConverter]::ToUint32( $utf32bytes )
"0x{0:X}" -f $codePoint
```

Output:

```
0x1F44D
```

For the character names, you could possibly find an answer here:
[Finding out Unicode character name in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2087682/7571258)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple script to get the name.  Note emojis are two surrogate chars.  Making a hash is faster than using where-object, even for one search of a 34,626 line file.

```
# idChar.ps1

param($inputChar)

if ($inputchar[0] -ge 0xD800 -and $inputchar[0] -le 0xDBFF -and
$inputchar.length -eq 1) {
  write-warning 'paste emojis with control v not right click, half of surrogate pair missing'
}

if (! (test-path $psscriptroot\UnicodeData.txt)) { 
  wget http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt -outfile UnicodeData.txt
}
$unicode = import-csv $psscriptroot\UnicodeData.txt -Delimiter ';' -Header hexcode,
  name
$unicode | % { $hash = @{} } { $hash[[int]('0x' + $_.hexcode)] = $_ }
$hash[[char]::ConvertToUtf32($inputChar,($index=0))]
```

Examples (control v to paste in console, not right click, to use psreadline's paste function):

```
.\idChar 

hexcode name
------- ----
1F44D   THUMBS UP SIGN


.\idChar —

hexcode name
------- ----
2014    EM DASH


.\idchar �

WARNING: paste emojis with control v not right click, half of surrogate pair missing
MethodInvocationException: C:\Users\ccfadmin\idChar.ps1:24
Line |
  24 |  $result = $hash[[char]::ConvertToUtf32($inputChar,$index)]
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "ConvertToUtf32" with "2" argument(s): "Found a high surrogate char without a following low
     | surrogate at index: 0. The input may not be in this encoding, or may not contain valid Unicode (UTF-16)
     | characters. (Parameter 's')"

inputchar hexcode name
--------- ------- ----
```