# How to get the Unicode script for a character in .NET?

Tags: .net, unicode

Is there a way to get the Unicode [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unicode)) (writing system) for a char in C#?

[CharUnicodeInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.charunicodeinfo?view=net-5.0) does not seem to provide this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with "plain" .NET... Even in .NET 5.0 the information contained in [UnicodeRanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.unicode.unicoderanges?view=net-5.0) is incomplete: only BMP characters (so characters that only need a single `char`) are described... With libraries like [UnicodeInfomation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnicodeInformation/) you can obtain the information you want. That library for example exposes the `Block`. Note that some alphabets (`Latin` for example) have various separate blocks assigned to them.

And see this: [Finding out Unicode character name in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087682/finding-out-unicode-character-name-in-net) If a library can give you the character name, surely it can give you its block.